# Is my current approach for switching a topic that Stream app is reading from to another topic viable or are there better ways?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to cut off a component of a data pipeline and rewire it. Currently, I have two KStream apps let's say A and B. App A consumes from a Kafka topic 1 and then processes to be published to another Kafka topic 2 and App B consumes from that topic. Is there a best practice of switching App B to consume directly from topic 1 without data loss and how would I go about testing that?

So far my current thoughts were to shut down App A and wait till all downstream messages are processed. Wait a bit and then stop App B. Then obtain the current offset from App A and set that as the new offset for App B and then start App B again.  I am still trying to diagram everything out before actually trying it and would want to test it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend watching consumer group lag from "app B", then if/when it reaches zero, you can shut it down and then change where it consumes from.

If possible, you can also stop any producers feeding "topic 1" so that  "app B" will be guaranteed to reach zero lag.

Comment: Does App B start reading from topic 1 latest message or will I need to actually set consumer offset?

Comment: Depends on if you've set `auto.offset.reset=latest`, but that'll only happen when you start the app for the first time... Kafka Streams automatically manages offsets

Comment: In App A I have `auto.offset.reset=latest` set but in App B it's not set in the application.yml. In this case what would happen, is the default just latest?

Comment: The default config is latest, yes